# Duplication employee in table due to switch in department

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem, my company has a customer satisfaction program which fetches a lot of data from different tables in our database systems.

The problem is I want to show customer satisfaction percentage of a **specific** department only, so only employees from this specific department are revealed.

The problem is in the table that i fetch the employees from, there are duplicates of the same employee if they have switched department, so if they worked in 1 department 1 year ago, and moved to another today, it will show me both as they are registered with the same `ID` even though they have switched department, the logic code in our SQL program is as follows:

```
"KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age ON " + (queryParams.JoinOnFirstAgent ? "FØRSTE_AGENT" : "SIDSTE_AGENT") + " = age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " +
                  "WHERE " + 
                      "TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) + " AND " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper)
```

I am not sure how to make sure that it only fetches the department the employee is active in today based on this sql query? I hope anyone can help me closer to a solution.

**EDIT:**

COMPLETE QUERY

```
var sql = "SELECT " + 
                      "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                      "KARAKTER, " +
                      "COUNT(*) AS COUNT " +
                  "FROM " + 
                      "KS_DRIFT.KT_KARAKTER kara " +
                  "LEFT JOIN " + 
                      "KS_DRIFT.KT_BESVARELSE besv ON kara.BESVARELSE_ID = besv.EKSTERN_ID AND kara.TYPE = besv.TYPE " +
                  "LEFT JOIN " +
                      "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age ON " + (queryParams.JoinOnFirstAgent ? "FØRSTE_AGENT" : "SIDSTE_AGENT") + " = age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " +
                  "WHERE " + 
                      "TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) + " AND " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper) + " AND " +
                      "SPØRGSMÅL_ID = " + queryParams.QuestionId +
                      (!queryParams.IncludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN IN (" + queryParams.IncludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                      (!queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN NOT IN (" + queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                      (!queryParams.AgentIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND AGENT_ID IN (" + queryParams.AgentIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                      (!queryParams.TeamIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND TEAM_ID IN (" + queryParams.TeamIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  "GROUP BY " +
                      "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                      "KARAKTER";
```

**Error message when using the suggested query by Gerard**

> ORA-00932: inkonsistente datatyper: forventede DATE, fik NUMBER
>      ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
>      ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
>      ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
>
> ### ved NDDataProvider.Database.Oracle.Connection.DBConnection.ExecuteQuery(String query) i S:\s0book\ND Udviklings Dokumentation\Git Repository dump - THOMAS HER\NDSolution\DOPe Data Provider\Database\Oracle\Connection\DBConnection.cs:linje 456

**OracleConversion.cs**

```
    public class OracleConversion {

    public static string ToOracleValue(object value) {
        if (value == null)
            return "null";

        if (value is string)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleString((String)value);

        if (value is Enum)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleInteger((int)value);

        int integerValue;

        if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out integerValue))
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleInteger(integerValue);

        decimal decimalValue;

        if (Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out decimalValue))
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleDecimal(decimalValue);

        if (value is Boolean)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleBoolean((Boolean)value);

        if (value is DateTime)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleDateTime((DateTime)value);

        if (value is NDUtilities.Time)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleInteger(((NDUtilities.Time)value).SecondsOfDay);

        if (value is SolutionsEntity)
            return OracleConversion.ToOracleInteger(((SolutionsEntity)value).Id);

        return OracleConversion.ToOracleString(value.ToString());
    }

    public static string ToOracleBoolean(Nullable<bool> booleanValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (booleanValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else
            returnValue = (booleanValue.Value) ? "1" : "0";

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string ToOracleInteger(Nullable<int> integerValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (integerValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else
            returnValue = integerValue.ToString();

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string ToOracleDecimal(Nullable<decimal> decimalValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (decimalValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else
            returnValue = decimalValue.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ".");

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string ToOracleString(string stringValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (stringValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else {
            returnValue = stringValue.Replace("'", "''");

            returnValue = "'" + returnValue + "'";
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string ToOracleDate(DateTime? dateTimeValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (dateTimeValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else
            returnValue = OracleConversion.ToOracleString(dateTimeValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string ToOracleDateTime(DateTime? dateTimeValue) {
        string returnValue;

        if (dateTimeValue == null)
            returnValue = "null";
        else
            returnValue = "TO_DATE(" + OracleConversion.ToOracleString(dateTimeValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) + ", " + OracleConversion.ToOracleString("yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss") + ")";

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please share some sample data in the table that holds that this info. Without knowing your data it's not easy to say how you would query it properly to get current employee<->department relationship.

Comment: Do you have any column in the table that represents the active department? If not, you will probably need to filter by a max date field. What does TIDSPUNKT represent?

Comment: An example in the database table is the ALLOCATION_START which in one example is where an employee started 2014-05-01 in one department and ALLOCATION_ENDED 2014-12-31, then ALLOCATION_START 2015-01-01 and ALLOCATION_ENDED 2100-0101, how do i choose the latest allocation_start only?

Comment: I don't have any table that represents active department, the only relevant information regarding their current department is the ALLOCATION_START and ALLOCATION_END

Comment: If you care about performance, don't "trunc(tidspunkt)" but use "where tidspunkt >= low_date and tidspunkt < upp_date + 1".

Comment: So the table `ALLOCATION` contains all times employees worked in departments. Accordingly, there is an employee ID and a department ID in the table and `ALLOCATION_START` and `ALLOCATION_END`. What are the columns for employee ID and department ID? What does `ALLOCATION_END` contain when the employee is still working there?

Comment: Yes that is correct Thorsten, the ALLOCATION_END contains the year 2100-01-01 on employees that are in their active department. So all employees that are still working in their department has the same end date.

Comment: And the column names are?

Comment: the EMPLOYEE ID column is named AGENT_ID and the department ID column is named TEAM_DEPARTMENT, it also has a TEAM_ID column

Answer (score 1):

Just add a test on sysdate and the allocation columns

```
var sql = "SELECT " +
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                  "KARAKTER, " +
                  "COUNT(*) AS COUNT " +
              "FROM " + 
                  "KS_DRIFT.KT_KARAKTER kara " +
              "LEFT JOIN " + 
                  "KS_DRIFT.KT_BESVARELSE besv ON kara.BESVARELSE_ID = besv.EKSTERN_ID AND kara.TYPE = besv.TYPE " +
              "LEFT JOIN " +
                  "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age ON " + (queryParams.JoinOnFirstAgent ? "FØRSTE_AGENT" : "SIDSTE_AGENT") + " = age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TIDSPUNKT >= ALLOCATION_START AND TIDSPUNKT < ALLOCATION_END + 1  " +
                  "and sysdate BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " +
              "WHERE TIDSPUNKT >= to_date(" +
                  OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) +
                  ",'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TIDSPUNKT < to_date(" +
                  OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper) +
                  ",'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1 AND " +
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID = " + queryParams.QuestionId +
                  (!queryParams.IncludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN IN (" + queryParams.IncludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN NOT IN (" + queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.AgentIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND AGENT_ID IN (" + queryParams.AgentIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.TeamIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND TEAM_ID IN (" + queryParams.TeamIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
              "GROUP BY " +
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                  "KARAKTER";
```

Comment: I am not sure where in the above code you want this test on sysdate? Do you mean instead of "TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) + " AND " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper)
" ?

Comment: I said to "add" it (to the join), so not "instead of".  Eg. before the "WHERE".   Give us the complete query and I'll put it in the right place.

Comment: I added the complete query in the edit on the original question because its too long for a comment

Comment: @kwesi1337: It seems your query is already considering this. It is selecting the employees that worked for the department at the TIDSPUNKT date. I don't know why you are using outer joins, though. And some where clause criteria seems to turn them into inner joins, but I cannot be sure, because unfortunately many columns in your query don't have a table qualifier (so we don't know where TIDSPUNKT, CDN, etc. reside in). You should fix this.

Comment: @kwesi1337: No. If you don't understand it, find somebody who does. Don't try to guess-fix.

Comment: I can't the person who wrote this whole application isn't working at my company anymore and he was a full-time graduated developer, this is just a student job for me so I don't have as much knowledge as he did, and I have only been working here for 2 months, so please cut me some slack. I am trying to get help, and i'm not trying to guess-fix anything but I cannot just rewrite this whole monolithic application if I can do an easy fix dude.

Comment: If there's something wrong with your modifications, Oracle will tell you.  And even a student can compare the results before and after a modification.  An interested student, I mean.

Comment: If not, just add a comment here.  LOL  SPØRGSMÅL = question.

Comment: BESVARELSE  (answer) was the only other word I didn't understand , being flemish.

Comment: I added the solution to the program and whenever i try to retrieve the data with the SQL query it gives me an error which has nothing to do with the actual problem: "Remote Server returned '550 5.7.129 RESOLVER.RST.RestrictedToRecipientsPermission; not authorized to send to recipient because the sender isn't on the recipient's list of senders to accept mail from'

Comment: That is a mail configuration problem.  Should the program send mail or is it trying to report a problem via mail?

Comment: Some mal account that's blocking your messages, as in https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1842161-exchange-2010-authentication-issue

Comment: Trying to report a problem via mail, but it's the comparison operators  that are crashing my program.

Comment: when i switch my BETWEEN to the >= then my program crashes

Comment: concatenating an sql statement is quite dangerous, you should be using bind variables.  What happens with var sql later on in the program?  Is the program C#, C++ or VB?  But between should work, it's only for performance improvement that I thought you could replace it.

Comment: C#, so if i don't want performance improvement I can use between and then i only need to edit the:   "and sysdate BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " + ?

Comment: :-(   I'm afraid so  :-(   (ie. YES)   Is "OracleConversion" a home made function?

Comment: Yes it's a homemade function.

Comment: I just read your other thread.  So, whenever there is a problem, the program sends a mail to papa, but papa doesn't want to know about it anymore.  You should be able to change the destination address somewhere, or disable this mail procedure.

Comment: Okay, now I changed it to my mail so I get the specific error message which is inconsistent datatypes, it asks for a DATE and gets a NUMBER, you can check original post i copied the complete error message

Comment: Please add sql contents also, I'd like to see what OracleConversion spits out.

Comment: When you ask for SQL content you mean that I provide you the code for OracleConversion? I added to the original post the complete code for the OracleConversion.cs

Comment: I meant the contents of the sql var, but it's OK, I can read C#.  So, OracleConversion is returning a string, with a date in format "yyyy-MM-dd".  Oracle SQL can't perform date arithmetic with a string, I'll modify my answer now, in case you ever need date arithmetic.

Comment: ... or better performance by getting rid of the "trunc(tidspunkt)".

Comment: Then I made a mistake.  It would help if you could publlsh the definition of the involved tables.

Comment: Thank you alot for your guidance, it is now working and not crashing anymore. I am sure you didn't make a mistake, I think somehow somewhere they have been given a wrong ID and the program thinks they are from the specific department even though they arent.

Comment: I hope you kept the original code too, so you can verify if this problem existed before your changes.

Comment: Yes I kept the original code, it's mysterious but my manager is on the case and will probably find out why exactly it does it. Your solution though is helpful so i consider this question solved.

Comment: If he doesn't, you know where to find me ;-)