# Oracle Database Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have been suggested a query that is crashing my CustomerSatisfaction program: 
This query is supposed to fetch information, and make sure that it only fetches the employees active in their department, meaning duplicates exist, and makes sure it only fetches the ones that are in the latest department which is defined by allocation_end. I use an Oracle DB and it crashes because of the comparison operators, eg the first greater than or equal to.

**Original query**

```
var sql = "SELECT " + 
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                  "KARAKTER, " +
                  "COUNT(*) AS COUNT " +
              "FROM " + 
                  "KS_DRIFT.KT_KARAKTER kara " +
              "LEFT JOIN " + 
                  "KS_DRIFT.KT_BESVARELSE besv ON kara.BESVARELSE_ID = besv.EKSTERN_ID AND kara.TYPE = besv.TYPE " +
              "LEFT JOIN " +
                  "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age ON " + (queryParams.JoinOnFirstAgent ? "FØRSTE_AGENT" : "SIDSTE_AGENT") + " = age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " +
              "WHERE " + 
                  "TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) BETWEEN " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) + " AND " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper) + " AND " +
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID = " + queryParams.QuestionId +
                  (!queryParams.IncludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN IN (" + queryParams.IncludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN NOT IN (" + queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.AgentIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND AGENT_ID IN (" + queryParams.AgentIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
                  (!queryParams.TeamIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND TEAM_ID IN (" + queryParams.TeamIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
              "GROUP BY " +
                  "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
                  "KARAKTER";
```

**Suggested query that is crashing my program:**

```
var sql = "SELECT " +
              "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
              "KARAKTER, " +
              "COUNT(*) AS COUNT " +
          "FROM " + 
              "KS_DRIFT.KT_KARAKTER kara " +
          "LEFT JOIN " + 
              "KS_DRIFT.KT_BESVARELSE besv ON kara.BESVARELSE_ID = besv.EKSTERN_ID AND kara.TYPE = besv.TYPE " +
          "LEFT JOIN " +
              "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age ON " + (queryParams.JoinOnFirstAgent ? "FØRSTE_AGENT" : "SIDSTE_AGENT") + " = age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TIDSPUNKT >= ALLOCATION_START AND TIDSPUNKT < ALLOCATION_END + 1  " +
              "and sysdate BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END " +
          "WHERE " + 
              "TIDSPUNKT >= " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Lower) + " AND TIDSPUNKT < " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.Interval.Upper) + " + 1 AND " +
              "SPØRGSMÅL_ID = " + queryParams.QuestionId +
              (!queryParams.IncludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN IN (" + queryParams.IncludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
              (!queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "AND CDN NOT IN (" + queryParams.ExcludeCDNs.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
              (!queryParams.AgentIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND AGENT_ID IN (" + queryParams.AgentIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
              (!queryParams.TeamIds.IsNullOrEmpty() ? " AND TEAM_ID IN (" + queryParams.TeamIds.ToDelimitedString(", ") + ") " : "") +
          "GROUP BY " +
              "SPØRGSMÅL_ID, " +
              "KARAKTER";
```

**Error message**

> ORA-00932: inkonsistente datatyper: forventede DATE, fik NUMBER ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck) ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior) ved Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()

Comment: I don't know C#, but there must be a way to use a prepared statement.  Instead of concatenating together a bunch of separate strings, which is error prone and time costly, just write out your entire query as a single string, and then _bind_ the dynamic values you want to use.  This also avoids SQL injection.

Comment: You should debug and show us the executed queries. Nobody wants to check you concats..

Comment: I already debugged enough of the program to know it's the comparison operators like this:  age.AGENT_INITIALS AND TIDSPUNKT >= ALLOCATION_START AND TIDSPUNKT < ALLOCATION_END + 1  " that crashes my program, the original query works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, in general you are right but you cannot bind an arbitrary number of values in `IN ()` expression - regardless of the language you are using.

Comment: Why are you using  TIDSPUNKT < ALLOCATION_END + 1 in your new query??

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing my program"? Any error message? Please show us the complete query, i.e. `Debug.Print(sql);`.

Comment: I was suggested it due to a problem regarding duplicates when an employee switches department, they are registrered 2 times in my DB table, and it fetches the old department in my Customersatisfaction program even though they moved to a new department. The original link to our discussion about how to fix it, is found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625356/duplication-employee-in-table-due-to-switch-in-department/50625592?noredirect=1#comment88262126_50625592

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no that does not work. The CSV string (e.g. `IN (1,2,3)`) would be treated as one value, i.e. `IN ('1,2,3')`

Comment: I already have this: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql); in my program, but i Build it and run the exe file so I don't get a erorr message.

Comment: As i am not sure about the datatype of TIDSPUNKT , I would suggest you to remove TIDSPUNKT < ALLOCATION_END + 1 and replace it with TIDSPUNKT <= ALLOCATION_END.

Comment: Yes, then please show us what you get from `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);` Do you mean your program is just stopping without any error?

Comment: TIDSPUNKT IS TIME so Date or Int, basically using any comparison operators will be crashing ti when trying to fetch data.

Comment: This si the only error message i receive, and that is not any actual errormessage other than saying that the former developer who no longer works here cannot receive the mail: Remote Server returned '550 5.7.129 RESOLVER.RST.RestrictedToRecipientsPermission; not authorized to send to recipient because the sender isn't on the recipient's list of senders to accept mail from'

Comment: I updated the original post with the error msg, its basically saying that it's inconsistent datatypes, expecting DATE but it receives NUMBER

Comment: I think the issue is with adding 1 to the date.
if you use <= and remove +1 then i assume it might work